# R sum rows of a data.frame, that contain only numbers in a certain column

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, subset

How to sum only the rows that contain a number in column b.

```
a <- c(1,5,3,1,-8,6,-1)
b <- c(4,-2,1,0,"c",2,"DX")

df <- data.frame(a,b)
df

#    a  b
# 1  1  4
# 2  5 -2
# 3  3  1
# 4  1  0
# 5 -8  c
# 6  6  2
# 7 -1  DX
```

I just can't seem how to sum the numeric rows only of the columb b.

In fact i have multiple data which are from multiples csv files that i read and store in r in form of dataframes with this code :

```
path <- "C:/Users/Visitor/Desktop/Unesco/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
for(file in files)
{
perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
assign(
gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

I can read them by typing their name(the csv files)

The problem is that some of the columns contains both numeric and character so i can't do a simple sum on them.

Comment: Ok thx but in fact my dataframe is in a list with a lot other data frame which have same columns names how i can do the same for all the df of the list?

Comment: d.b that dont works i get the error NAs introduced by coercion in sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your `data.frame` or converting factors to character in your existing `data.frame`. Then you could extract numeric values into a new column, which you can sum with regular tidyverse tools.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(1,5,3,1,-8,6,-1)
b <- c(4,-2,1,0,"c",2,"DX")

df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% 
  mutate(b_numbers = parse_double(b)) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(b_numbers, na.rm = T))
#> Warning: 2 parsing failures.
#> row col expected actual
#>   5  -- a double     c 
#>   7  -- a double     DX
#>   sum
#> 1   5
```

This approach generalizes nicely to working on multiple columns:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(parse_double)) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = T)))
#> Warning: 2 parsing failures.
#> row col expected actual
#>   5  -- a double     c 
#>   7  -- a double     DX
#>   a b
#> 1 7 5
```

If you have many `data.frame`s like this, you could turn it into a function and map it to your list:

```r
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(suppressWarnings(parse_double(.)))) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = T)))
}

# create list with multiple data.frames
my_list <- list(a = df, b = df)

my_list %>% 
  map(my_fun)
#> $a
#>   a b
#> 1 7 5
#> 
#> $b
#>   a b
#> 1 7 5
```

Like `d.b` pointed out, you may use `suppressWarnings()` to silence the warnings from `parse_double`. I would prefer `parse_double` over `as.numeric` in this example, since it is informative about what is happening.

**Edit**: 
Since you stated in your comment to the original question, that the columns of your `data.frame`s always have the same names, you could use `mutate_at` and `summarise_at`:

```r
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate_at("b", funs(suppressWarnings(parse_double(.)))) %>% 
    summarise_at("b", funs(sum(., na.rm = T)))
}
```

or for multiple columns:

```r
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate_at(c("a", "b"), funs(suppressWarnings(parse_double(.)))) %>% 
    summarise_at(c("a", "b"), funs(sum(., na.rm = T)))
}
```

Comment: Thx very much but what if all my dataframes dont have the same name?

Comment: @JulienNguyen This doesn't matter. With this approach you can have different column names in each `data.frame`, and each element of the list could have a different name, as long as you are ok with always summing all columns in each `data.frame`. I edited my answer slightly to reflect that.

Comment: What i write instead of df in the function if i have two dataframe called "Fichier1" and "Fichier2"?

Comment: @JulienNguyen My naming of arguments for the function was poor. I changed it to `x` to better show, that the function operates on each element of the list, regardless of what those elements are named.

Comment: Wait but if i want to do the sum only on 2 or 3 columns not all how i can do that?

Comment: @JulienNguyen Take a look at `mutate_at` and `mutate_if`. Depending on your specific problem either of those could work. If you provide more data, I can show you how.

Comment: @JulienNguyen I re-read your comment to the original question and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry i don't see how this code can sum only for example columns d,x,j out of a until z columns.

Comment: I didn't see your edit sorry this code is so useful i can apply other function than sum also?

Comment: @JulienNguyen Surely!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sum by row:

```
a <- c(1,5,3,1,-8,6,-1)
b <- c(4,-2,1,0,"c",2,"DX")

df <- data.frame(a,b = as.numeric(b))
rowSums(df)
```

For only the non-na's:

```
rowSums(df[!is.na(df$b),])
```

If you want by column:

```
colSums(df[!is.na(df$b),])
```

or depending on what you want to sum in the columns:

```
colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: From you comments above, I believe you are looking for an output given by last line of code `colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: In fact in my case i do a loop to read multiple csv files into many dataframes so i can't do your method since it requires to create the df.But i believe it works yes sorry.